# Multi-process application that uses signals

Tags: c

Multi-process application that uses signals.

a.       The parent process should create two child process which would create and unlink a file respectively.

b.      The parent process should register for SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2. These signals can be sent to the parent from the command line in another terminal.

c.       If the user sends SIGUSR1 to parent from another terminal, the parent in-turn should send this signal to child 1. Child 1 should create a file.

d.      If the user sends SIGUSR2 to parent from another terminal, the parent in-turn should send this signal to child 2. Child 2 should unlink this file

please can any one help me how to slove this program using c language?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is OS specific. I guess it is on Linux (but not tagged as such). You should avoid using signals as an inter-process communication mechanism. You should use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), or [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets instead. See also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us something we can help you with, not an assignment for us to do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this program, this will solve your requirement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int parent;
int pid_1;
int pid_2;
void signal_handler1(int signo)
{
    int pid=getpid();
    if(signo == SIGUSR1)
    {
        if(pid == parent)
            kill(pid_1,SIGUSR1);
        if(pid == pid_1)
        {
            int fd=open("/tmp/test",O_CREAT,0755);
            close(fd);
        }
    }
    if(signo == SIGUSR2)
    {
        if(pid == parent)
            kill(pid_2,SIGUSR2);
        if(pid == pid_2)
            unlink("test");
    }
}
main()
{
    parent=getpid();
    signal(SIGUSR1,signal_handler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2,signal_handler1);
    if((pid_1=fork()) <-1)
        exit(0);
    else if(pid_1 == 0)
        pid_1=getpid();
    else
    {
        if((pid_2=fork()) <-1)
            exit(0);
        else if(pid_2 == 0)
            pid_2=getpid();
    }
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your child process PID's in the parent
Use `signal(SIGUSR1, &sig_handler);` (man 2 signal) to intercept yous signals in the parent.
Then in your 2 sig_handlers, use `kill(child_pid, SIGUSRX);` (man 2 kill).
In your childs, use signal() again, and create appropriates handlers (they will create the file etc)